# Ruby Automation Testing for Web Control on .NET Form

Tags: ruby, testing, automated-tests, watir-webdriver, rautomation

I'm trying use Ruby Automation to test a web application that is being displayed through a web control on a .NET form instead of your typical browser (like Internet Explorer, Firefox, etc...) and I'm not having much luck.

I am able to use the Watir gem to access all the elements when the web page is being displayed through Internet Explore. But how do you access elements on a web page if the application is made using a .NET vb form with some kind of web control to display the website? Are there ways to use RAutomation or Watir gems to access the web elements? Or does anyone have any other suggestions that might work for me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so that it's doable. At least not with the tools you've mentioned. However, i'd test that web application as a regular web application - e.g. through a browser - and create a separate tests to test the integration part of .NET and web application.